# orderby method use 2 case in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sql-order-by, case

i can use orderby method in laravel
like this

```
return $this->hasMany('Link')->orderBy('quality', 'desc');
```

its okay i want use like this

```
CASE `lang`
         WHEN 'a' THEN 1
         WHEN 'as' THEN 2
         WHEN 'asd' THEN 3
         END
,CASE `quality`
         WHEN 'd' THEN 1
         WHEN 'ds' THEN 2
         WHEN 'dsa' THEN 3
         WHEN 'dsaa' THEN 4
         WHEN 'dsaaa' THEN 6
         WHEN 'dsaaaa' THEN 7
         WHEN 'dsaaaaa' THEN 8
         WHEN 'dsaaaaaaaaa' THEN 9
         WHEN 'dsaaaa' THEN 10
         END,views DESC
```

How can i write this in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN <CONDITION> THEN <column1> ELSE <column2> END DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any algorithm behind the numbers? Could `` ORDER BY LENGTH(`lang`), LENGTH(`quality`), views DESC `` do the job?

Comment: it is table row

Comment: What is table row? How do you determine which number is used for which data stored in `lang` and `quality`?